# Is there a kubernetes role definition to allow the command `kubectl rollout restart deploy <deployment>`?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

I want a deployment in kubernetes to have the permission to restart itself, from within the cluster.

I know I can create a serviceaccount and bind it to the pod, but I'm missing the name of the most specific permission (i.e. not just allowing `'*'`) to allow for the command

```
kubectl rollout restart deploy <deployment>
```

here's what I have, and ??? is what I'm missing

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: restart-sa
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: restarter
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    verbs: ["list", "???"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: testrolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: restart-sa
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: restarter
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
  serviceAccountName: restart-sa
```

Comment: You can likely confirm this with `kubectl --v=100` or if you have the kube-apiserver's audit log for the operation, but I _believe_ that just `kubectl annotate deployment com.example/whatever=$(date +%s)` type deal, merely bumping some meaningless piece of metadata that will then cause the Pods to roll over. Thus, I would guess the RBAC is either `label` or `annotate`, whichever that command uses under the hood

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the following is the minimum permissions required to restart a deployment:

```
rules:
 - apiGroups: ["apps", "extensions"]
   resources: ["deployments"]
   resourceNames: [$DEPLOYMENT]
   verbs: ["get", "patch"]
```

Comment: "extensions" was not required in my case. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that this allows editing deployments which allows for more tampering with applications than just rolling out restarts.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is also facing this issue, I faced a similar one where the service account couldn't perform the **rollout restart**.

At the end I managed to fix it by adding **replicasets** to the list of **resources**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: restarter
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "patch"]
```

Hope this helps you as well :)

Comment: This is the correct answer as opposed to the most rated one

Answer (score 0):

If you want permission to restart kubernetes deployment itself from within the cluster you need to set  permission on [rbac authorisation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

In the yaml file you have missed some specific permissions under [Role:rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example) you need to add in the below format
verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

Instead of “Pod” you need to add “deployment” in the [yaml file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

Make sure that you add “serviceAccountName: restart-sa”  in the deployment yaml file  under “spec:containers.” As mentioned below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1  
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      serviceAccountName: restart-sa
```

Then you can restart the deployment using the below command:

**$** **kubectl rollout restart deployment [deployment_name]**